# Should SSIS OData source have an XML config file?

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata, config

I am getting a Root Element Is Missing error when I test all my OData connections to Sharepoint.

Root element is missing. (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.ODataConnectionManager)

I can only find dll files and not an xml file.  I can see xml files for other connections, but not this (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.ODataConnectionManager).  Should it exist as an xml file and if not how do I deal with the root element missing error?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few common reasons and solutions for this error:

Empty Response or Invalid XML:

Check if the response you're getting from SharePoint CSOM is empty or not well-formed XML. If the response is empty or doesn't contain a valid XML root element, it can trigger this error. Ensure that the CSOM request is being formed correctly and is sending the necessary information to SharePoint.

Incorrect Content Type:

Ensure that the content type specified in the request headers is correct. The content type should be set to "application/xml" or "text/xml" depending on the scenario.

Encoding Issues:

Check if there are any encoding issues with the XML data being sent or received. Ensure that the XML data is encoded properly, and the encoding type is specified in the headers.